# Cherem ceremony: candles?

Tags: sources-mekorot, candle-lighting, cherem

Encyclopedia Judaica (sv 'Herem') says that when a cherem was pronounced, a ceremony would be held in synagogue involving wax candles. Can anyone point to sources discussing this ceremony?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the Bet Yosef [Y"D 228:39](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Responsa_Maharashdam%2C_Yoreh_Deah.97.3?vhe=She%27elot_uTeshuvot_Maharashdam,_Lemberg,_1862&lang=bi) and the Mahrshdam [Y"D 97](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Responsa_Maharashdam%2C_Yoreh_Deah.97.3?vhe=She%27elot_uTeshuvot_Maharashdam,_Lemberg,_1862&lang=bi) mention that a Cherem is more severe when done with **extinguishing candles** - and is harder to undo.

> וכן מצאתי בשיטת הר"י ן' מיניר ז"ל וז"ל אם הוסיפו ואמרו שלא יוכלו להתיר דינו כדין נדר ושבועה שאינו ניתר אלא על ידי חכם ובפתח היתר כראוי והוסיף הרא"ה כי כל שהוסיפו חומרא בחרם על מנהגם הראשון כגון התרועות או נאדות נפוחים או **כיבו נרות** וכיוצא באלו גלו אדעתייהו דלהחמיר באו ואינו ניתר כשאר החרמות אלא ע"י שאלה עכ"ל

Similarly in [Kav haYashar 29:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kav_HaYashar.29.4?vhe=Kav_HaYashar,_Metsudah_Publications,_2007&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - with more detail:

> בְאִם אֲשֶׁר יֵשׁ נָשִׁים כַּשְׁפָנִיּוֹת, הַיּוֹדְעוֹת לְהַזִּיק יַלְדֵי יִשְׂרְאֵלִים, רְאוּיִן הֵן לְפָרְטָן בִּשְׁמָם וּלְהַחֲרִים אוֹתָן בְּחֵרֶם חָמוּר בְּשׁוֹפָר **וְכִבּוּי נֵרוֹת** וּבְהוֹצָאַת שִׁבְעָה סִפְרֵי תּוֹרָה, וּלְהַפְרִישׁ אוֹתָן שֶׁלֹּא יִהְיֶה לָהֶם שׁוּם נְגִיעָה בִּקְדֻשַּׁת יִשְׂרָאֵל. ‏
>
> And if certain women are known to harm Jewish children through their sorcery it is fitting that they be pointed out by name and that a severe ban be proclaimed against them, accompanied with shofar blowing and the **extinguishing of candles** and in the presence of seven Torah scrolls. They should then be ostracized so that they have no contact with the holy community of Israel.

Comment: And Shulchan Aruch 228:25 - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.228.25?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en

Comment: Does נר refer specifically to a wax candle? Or perhaps a lamp of any kind?

Comment: @Zev classically it means lamp only (like in the Temple, and "who commanded us to light the Shabbat lamps"). I don't know if it gained the meaning of wax candle before this source was written.